# Rails Papertrail - display who Was Responsible for last change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, paper-trail-gem

I'm using Devise and Papertrail and would like to display which user made the most recent update ([documentation link](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#finding-out-who-was-responsible-for-a-change)).

In controller:

```
  def show
    # @history = @person.versions.last 
    @last_change = @person.versions.last
    @user_who_made_the_change = User.find @last_change.whodunnit.to_i
  end
```

In show page

```
 <%= @user_who_made_the_change %>
```

However I get the resulting error:
**undefined method `whodunnit' for nil:NilClass**

in *app/controllers/people_controller.rb:15:in `show'*

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: It seems that @person.versions is returning nothing, so last change is nil and the app crashes. Is it possible that you really didn't do any changes on that specific person after setting up the paper_trail gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons for omit save version data (configuration, save without callbacks, save from console ...)

I think you must check if you have the information to show:

```
def show
  @last_change = @person.versions.last
  @user_who_made_the_change = (User.find(@last_change.whodunnit.to_i) if @last_change && @last_change.whodunnit) || nil
end
```

This must do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to modify initializer to kept template clean.

config/initializers/paper_trail.rb

```
PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!

module PaperTrail
  class Version < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
  end
end
```

history.html.erb

```
<% @versions.each do |version| %>
  <%= version.user.email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok this approach looks nice, but when I put into view: <b>WHO:</b> <%= version.user.email %><br/>  it fails...works only when I use: <b>WHO:</b> <%= version.whodunnit %><br/> this returns mer ID of the user

Comment: I am getting the same problem. My guess is it has to do with paper trail storing as a string and User id being a bigint. Will post back if I find out the 'Year 2020' solution

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit of googling this evening about this topic. I simply wanted to be able to write something like `@post.versions.last.user` and get the devise User record (ie the person *whodunnit* that version).

The way that worked for me was creating the `paper_trail.rb` initializer with

```rb
PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!

module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
     include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
     belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
  end
end
```

Some solutions gave me errors including *json col not set or something* and/or `undefined method`timestamp_sort_order'`.

This is just what worked for me.

Other options included creating this in your `app/models` which I liked the idea of but never tried cause this 'worked' and I have other code I want to write :)